# Como fazer exponenciação em Java?

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um **exercício de juros compostos** e tenho esse código que se segue até o momento.

```
public class ExDesafio_Aula1 {
        public static void main(String[]args){
            double investimento = 5000.00;
            double juros = 0.01;

            double valorFinal = investimento * (1 + juros) * 12;
            System.out.println(valorFinal);
    }
}
```

O problema é que no final da conta, ele deveria elevar o valor entre parênteses por 12, e não multiplicá-lo.

Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 9):

Tente usar [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,double)):

```
public class ExDesafio_Aula1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double investimento = 5000.00;
        double juros = 0.01;

        double valorFinal = investimento * Math.pow(1 + juros, 12);
        System.out.println(valorFinal);
    }
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/NNgeBd)

Comment: Fiz recentemente um calculo onde minhas variáveis eram todas números inteiros (resultado = Math.pow (base, expoente)), e ao compilar era me retornado um erro de incompatibilidade de tipo, por que a variável resultado estava declarada como inteiro. Solucionei declarando ela como um double.

A minha variável que vai receber o resultado de um calculo feito com Math.pow sempre tem que ser double ? Mesmo que o resultado seja inteiro ?

Comment: @Snickers Veja essa outra resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304447/132

Answer (score -3):

A diferença é que se você usar ** a resposta é um valor real e se você usar ^ o resultado é um inteiro.

8 ** 3
A resposta seria 512.00

8 ^ 3
A resposta seria 512

8.5 ** 3
A resposta seria 614.125

8.5 ^ 3
A resposta seria 614

Radiciação pela potência
Indice - raiz | radicando = radicando elevado a 1/indice
Exemplo: raiz cubica de 512 = 512 elevado 1/3 -> 512 * *(1 / 3)

Comment: Essa resposta não faz sentido. A linguagem em questão é [**Java**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/) onde não existe o operador aritmético `**`  e o operador `^` é o or binário. Veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/1YHocL) e [aqui](https://ideone.com/rW6Feh).

Comment: Sim na verdade eu vi essa forma de usar potencia em outra linguagem e acreditava que java tinha algo parecido. Devo remover essa lógica informada acima???

Comment: Corrija a informação veiculada, tornando sua publicação em algo útil para os usuários de java. Veja [ask] e também veja a [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade).

Comment: ***Errata**: Veja [Answer]