# Dúvida sobre Recursividade em um método de potência

Tags: java, recursão

Não entendi como funciona a recursividade no método que realiza a potenciação.

```
public class calculaPotencia {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("digite um número inteiro para base: ");
            int base = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("digite um número inteiro para o expoente: ");
            int exp = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("A potencia de " +base+ " elevado a " +exp+ " é: " + potencia(base,exp));
        System.exit(0);
    }
    static int potencia(int b,int e){
        if (e==1)
            return b;
        else
            return (potencia(b,e-1)*b);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro vou dar uma arrumada no código:

```
public class CalculaPotencia {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite um número inteiro para base: ");
        int base = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Digite um número inteiro para o expoente: ");
        int exp = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("A potência de " + base
                + " elevado a " + exp + " é: " + potencia(base, exp));
    }

    public static int potencia(int b, int e) {
        if (e == 0) return 1;
        return potencia(b, e - 1) * b;
    }
}
```

Observe que mudei a condição do `if`. Isso é importante porque o seu código original não sabia lidar com o caso do expoente ser zero.

Vejamos um pouco de matemática:

> Peguemos por exemplo, 3<sup>5</sup>:
>
> 3<sup>5</sup> = 3 × 3 × 3 × 3 × 3 = (3 × 3 × 3 × 3) × 3 = 3<sup>4</sup> × 3

Observe que nesse exemplo, reduzimos a exponenciação pela potência 5 a uma exponenciação pela potência 4 e uma multiplicação. Ou seja, reduzimos `potencia(3, 5)` para `potencia(3, 4) * 3`. Aqui ocorre a recursão.

Prosseguindo:

> 3<sup>4</sup> = 3 × 3 × 3 × 3 = (3 × 3 × 3) × 3 = 3<sup>3</sup> × 3
>
> 3<sup>3</sup> = 3 × 3 × 3 = (3 × 3) × 3 = 3<sup>2</sup> × 3
>
> 3<sup>2</sup> = 3 × 3 = (3) × 3 = 3<sup>1</sup> × 3
>
> 3<sup>1</sup> = 3

No código, isso aí em cima é equivalente a isto aqui em baixo:

> 3<sup>5</sup> = 3<sup>4</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 4)` × 3
>
> 3<sup>4</sup> = 3<sup>3</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 3)` × 3
>
> 3<sup>3</sup> = 3<sup>2</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 2)` × 3
>
> 3<sup>2</sup> = 3<sup>1</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 1)` × 3
>
> 3<sup>1</sup> = 3

Ou seja, na sua pilha de chamadas você tem:

```
potencia(3, 5)
potencia(3, 4)
potencia(3, 3)
potencia(3, 2)
potencia(3, 1)
```

E é aqui que o seu algoritmo original para e retorna `3` (a base). E então ele começa a usar o resultado computado e ir desempilhando essas chamadas do `potencia(3, 1)` até o `potencia(3, 5)`:

> Resultado de `potencia(3, 1)`: 3<sup>1</sup> = 3
>
> Resultado de `potencia(3, 2)`: 3<sup>2</sup> = 3<sup>1</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 1)` × 3 = 3 × 3 = 9
>
> Resultado de `potencia(3, 3)`: 3<sup>3</sup> = 3<sup>2</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 2)` × 3 = 9 × 3 = 27
>
> Resultado de `potencia(3, 4)`: 3<sup>4</sup> = 3<sup>3</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 3)` × 3 = 27 × 3 = 81
>
> Resultado de `potencia(3, 5)`: 3<sup>5</sup> = 3<sup>4</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 4)` × 3 = 81 × 3 = 243

Ou seja, o que o método `potencia` está fazendo é reduzir a potenciação por `e` por uma multiplicação pela potência `e - 1`. Como isso é recursivo, a potenciação por `e - 1` vai por sua vez ser reduzida a uma potenciação por `e - 2`, que será reduzida por uma potenciação por `e - 3`, até que a potência seja 1.

E porque eu mudei o `if` para parar na potência 0 ao invés de 1? Porque no caso do expoente ser 0, o resultado da potência é sempre 1 e o caso do expoente ser 1 também se reduz para uma multiplicação pelo expoente 0 tal como nos outros expoentes, produzindo isso:

> Resultado de `potencia(3, 0)`: 1
>
> Resultado de `potencia(3, 1)`: 3<sup>1</sup> = 3<sup>0</sup> × 3 = `potencia(3, 0)` × 3 = 1 × 3 = 3